# Conversion RGB to xyY with colormath

Tags: python, rgb, colormath

With colormath I make a conversion from RGB to xyY value. It works fine for 1 RGB value, but I can't find the right code to do the conversion for multiple RGB values imported from an Excel. I use to following code:

```
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, xyYColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Color/Fontane/RGB/FontaneHuco.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['R', 'G', 'B'])
#print(df)


rgb = sRGBColor(df['R'],df['G'],df['B'], is_upscaled=True)
xyz = convert_color(rgb, xyYColor)

print(xyz)
```

But when i run this code i receive to following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\Overige\Chroma.py", line 9, in <module>
    lab = sRGBColor(df['R'], df['G'], df['B'])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\colormath\color_objects.py", line 524, in __init__
    self.rgb_r = float(rgb_r)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 141, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this problem?

[image: Excel dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert_color` is expecting floats and you're giving it dataframe columns instead. You need to apply the conversion one row at at time, which can be done as follows:

```py
xyz = df.apply(
    lambda row: convert_color(
        sRGBColor(row.R, row.G, row.B, is_upscaled=True), xyYColor
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

Comment: It works perfect. 1 other question: I want to export the outcome to Excel in 3 different columns. At this moment it is all in 1 column. Do you have an idea how to split the outcome? @Seon

Comment: You could run it through another `df.apply`, with a function looking like `lambda row: row.xyy_x` to get 3 dataframes and then combine them before saving to csv.

Comment: I am not that familiar with this, can you an example? Thanks

Comment: `xyz_x = xyz.apply(lambda row: row.xyy_x)`. Do the same for `y` and `Y` to get 3 Series: `xyz_x`, `xyz_y` and `xyz_Y`.  You can then create a dataframe from them: `frame = pd.DataFrame({ 'x': xyz_x, 'y': xyz_y, 'Y',: 'xyz_Y})`. 
There probably is a more efficient way of doing this, but I can't think of it.